# Error: member reference base type '*****' (aka '*****') is not a structure or union

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

When I try to access to my structure in a function where I pass it through reference, the compiler shows this error:

```
error: member reference base type 'Pila' (aka 'struct tipoCelda *') is not a structure or union
        **p = p->sig;**
```

Here it is the prototype of the structure in the header file:

```
typedef int tipoElemento;

typedef struct tipoCelda { 
    tipoElemento elemento; 
    struct tipoCelda * sig; 
    } tipoCelda;

typedef tipoCelda * Pila;
```

And this is the function where I get the error :

```
tipoElemento pilaSuprime (Pila *p){

    tipoElemento borrado;

    if (pilaVacia(p) == 1)
        printf ("\n\nNO SE PUEDE BORRAR.La pila esta vacia\n");
    else{
        borrado = p->elemento;

        p->elemento = 0;
        p = p->sig;
    }

    return borrado;
}
```

I get the message due to these 3 lines:

```
borrado = p->elemento;

            p->elemento = 0;
            p = p->sig;
```

I declare the stack in main and then call the function:

```
Pila variablePila;

//////OTHER ACTIONS//////

pilaSuprime(variablePila)
```

I am trying to delete a node of a linked list that acts like a stack but I can´t compile it.

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing `&variablePila` to the function from your main function? Your function takes a `Pila*`, not a `Pila`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn´t inserting the node in the right way.
With this method now it works!

```
int pilaInserta (Pila *p,tipoElemento elemento){

Pila nuevo;

nuevo = (Pila) malloc (sizeof(Pila));
if (nuevo == NULL){
    printf ("Error al crear el nuevo nodo de la pila\n");
    return 0;
}

nuevo->elemento = elemento;
if (*p == NULL){ //Si estaba vacia y es el primero
    *p = nuevo;
    nuevo->sig = NULL;
}
else{
    nuevo->sig = *p; //Apuntamos al que estaba primero
    *p = nuevo;
}

return 0;
```

}

And for deleting the node is like one user wrote:

```
tipoElemento pilaSuprime (Pila *p){

    tipoElemento borrado;

    if (pilaVacia(p) == 1)
        printf ("\n\nNO SE PUEDE BORRAR.La pila esta vacia\n");
    else{
        borrado = (*p)->elemento;

        (*p)->elemento = 0;
        p = (*p)->sig;

        printf ("\n\nEl elemento borrado es: %d\n",borrado);
    }

    return borrado;
}
```